# Добавить объект в valarray

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно добавить объект в `valarray`. 
Есть `valarray`

```
valarray<Inspector> InspectorData;
```

Пытаюсь добавить таким способом:

```
InspectorData.operator+= (Inspector(chNameDep, chTown, chRegion, chStreet, iBuilding, chNameInsp, chSurnameInsp, chPatronymicInsp, chPosition, chRank, iAge));
```

Но получаю ошибку.

> ```
> C2676    бинарный "+=": "Inspector" не определяет этот оператор или преобразование к типу приемлемо к встроенному оператору.
> ```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить элемент.

Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы конечно можете создать обьект  `valarray<Inspector>`, но:

- если  `Inspector` не имеет аргументы по умолчанию:

Вы должны сразу обозначить эти аргументы и количество:

```
  valarray<Inspector> inspactorData(Inspector(arg1, arg2,...), 10);
```

тогда вы получаете `inspactorData` с 10 обьектами  `Inspector(arg1, arg2,...)`, которые потом можете заменить другими.

- Если же Inspector имеет все таки конструктор по умолчанию, то:

вы можете создать обьект

```
 valarray<Inspector> inspactorData;
```

но потом придется установить размер(сколько обьектов предположительно будет содержать)

```
inspactorData.resize(10);
 inspactorData[0] = Inspector(chNameDep, chTown, chRegion, chStreet, iBuilding, chNameInsp,
                              chSurnameInsp, chPatronymicInsp, chPosition, chRank, iAge);
```

Так можете заполнять каждый элемент  объекта  `valarray`. Все его операторы  приводят к вызову операторов элементов `valarray`. Так что ваши попытки добавлять с помощью оператора + приводят к тому, что вы суммируете  содержащийся в последовательности все обьекты с другим обьектом, что во первых не то, что вы ожидаете, а во вторых ваш класс может не иметь определение  `operator+`

Но `valarray`  оптимизирован для численных методов, для других целей использовать его просто нежелательно, а иногда даже приведет к тупику. Так что конкретно для вашего класса, лучше используйте контейнеры ( "не совсем котейнер": такую характеристику дал `valarray` классу Страуструп )

Comment: Спасибо большое за пояснение.

Answer (score -1):

Для хранения в `valarray` класс должен соответствовать спецификации [Numric type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/NumericType). Класс с названием `Inspector` не очень похож на число. Более того, оператор += в данном случае служит для поэлементного сложения векторов, а не для добавления. Короче говоря используйте `std::vector`, тогда добавить элемент можно так:

```
::std::vector<Inspector> InspectorData{};
InspectorData.emplace_back(chNameDep, chTown, chRegion, chStreet, iBuilding, chNameInsp, chSurnameInsp, chPatronymicInsp, chPosition, chRank, iAge);
```

Comment: не совсем правильное утверждение